# What do you call a circular paved protuberance added to a paved street?

Tags: phrases, terminology

I used to own a house located in a modern suburban street with a circular protuberance, a circular paved (tarred) surface appended to the paved street it was part of. Four houses with their gardens were positioned around this circular paved street area. The number of properties in the street was thus increased by three. The point of entry into the circular paved area had the width of the street. This drive-in entry area could have accommodated one property. By serving as the entrance to the circular paved area, it allowed three extra properties to be erected. What is the name of such a circular paved street area?

Comment: Do you mean something like a cul-de-sac, as seen in [this image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a6/Cul-de-sac80020_copy.jpg/800px-Cul-de-sac80020_copy.jpg)?

Comment: I thought a cul-de-sac was a side street with a dead end, the dead end sometimes widening or ending in a circular paved area so a vehicle can be turned around. The house I owned was one of four properties arranged around a paved circular area. There was no side street. We turned directly into the circular paved area through a turn-off (or turn-in) opening from the street. I would like to write: "I walked across the [paved circular street area] to the house of my neighbour." Is there a word for the "paved circular street area"? By the way: How do I attach a picture here? And why "0 answers"?

Comment: You need rep to attach a picture. Zero answers, because there aren't any yet. There is a "protuberance" such as you describe in the bottom-right-hand corner of Janus' image; is that what you mean?

Comment: Is this US, UK, Australia or somewhere else?

Comment: In my experience, people don't differentiate much between the whole dead-end street and the round bit at the end. They call both a _cul-de-sac_ or _court._

Comment: I have to reiterate what Bradd Szonye said above: COURT COURT COURT is the name that is used, at least on the US West Coast. Court: A street that dead ends in a circular turnaround area that is at the same time also used to expand the number of driveways and houses that can be placed at the end of said street. Example: Google map  Coral Ct,
San Jose, California.

Answer (score 6):

A **cul-de-sac** (or **no-through-road**) is — at least in British usage — normally a separate road/street in its own right, with its own road name.

In the village where I live, we have a modern estate where two groups of houses are accessed by a 'shared driveway' as shown in the Google satellite picture below (see top right & bottom left).

[image]

These are not circular in shape, but they do meet your description of maximising the use of land by several properties while using little immediate road-side space. Here, they are not 'extensions' of the main road but akin to shared 'driveways' because you *do* have to cross the pavement (AmE *sidewalk*) to access the driveway, just as you would for a single house. I do not know of a specific name for this type of arrangment, but if there is one, it could well differ from country to country.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say *turning area* was the most common term, sometimes *turning circle*, but that could be confused with the space required to turn a particular vehicle around.  Incidentally they're now normally Y- or T-shaped in new build, because that makes it easier to turn large vehicles (rubbish lorries, fire engines, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Continuing the tradition of pretentious diction you could borrow the French term **fond de raquette** (French for "bottom of racket"), or you might want to combine the two languages and label it as a [**turnaround cul de sac**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/turnaround?s=t) or a [**turnaround impasse**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/impasse?s=t).

In London these configurations are quite common and usually referred to as **grove** and **close**. There is an East End street called *Frying Pan Alley*, although in this particular instance the name is believed to historically reflect the presence of braziers and ironmongers.

Answer (score 1):

An area in a road that forms a circle with an open area in the middle is often called a [*roundabout*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/roundabout) or traffic circle

> a road junction in which traffic streams circulate around a central island (US and Canadian name: traffic circle)

Roundabouts usually occur where there are additional roads that meet at the circle.

A widening in a street or road that has a central area is often called a *[plaza](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/plaza)*.

> a large open area with a hard surface in a city or town

These tend to be larger, and the central area usually has a public purpose.

Comment: In the UK, a roundabout (*never* a 'traffic circle') would be used at a road *junction* and would be a raised area in the middle of the junction, but (if I understand OP's question correctly) it would not be used to describe the arrangement described by OP.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I need to attach a drawing of my circular street "protuberance" to show exactly what I mean. According to Andrew Leach I need "rep" to attach a picture file. What might the word "rep" mean here? I'm afraid I don't have "rep" as far as I know. The circular paved area was not really meant for turning a car. Four private driveways branched off from it. Two cars reversing from their respective driveways had their rear ends pointed towards each other. One walked almost straight ahead - at a slight angle - over the circular paved area towards any of three front doors.

Comment: @Tellme rep (short for reputation points) is the number by your name. You currently have 24 rep. I think that's enough to post images, I think the threshold is 10.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to suggest something a bit unusual:

> **appendix:** a : appendage b : supplementary material usually attached at the end of a piece of writing

The paving you describe does the same as a literary appendix- allows the addition of extra material.  I might use this in giving directions, but I wouldn't tell someone that I was "walking across the appendix."

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct term is a **lollipop**, and if you wanted to push it, a **lollipop side street**, or even a **lollipop-shaped side street**.

**Loop** is also a possibility, but who wants to live in a loop if you have the chance to live at a lollipop?

Okay, I've had my fun. Here's a Web reference for [Residential Street Pattern Design](http://www.cmhc-schl.gc.ca/publications/en/rh-pr/tech/socio75.html) to back up my submission.

Comment: Lollypop doesn't quite reflect the three dimensional configuration you think you are describing.

Comment: @user49727 three dimensional configuration? Road surfaces are two dimensional. Are you referring to sink holes? Then, I agree. My years on a survey crew never exposed me to a three dimensional road or street configuration. BTW, my original spelling was incorrect, Lollipop is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you google the term ["**Circular Drive**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=circular+drive&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=SjInUtWQGtPFsATKj4GIBA&ved=0CFAQsAQ&biw=1274&bih=973) you will find a great number of pictures that match exactly the thing you're speaking about.

I don't think the number of houses that a situated on the drive is an important factor in its naming.  Consider in estate sites, such a drive may include the owners' house, as well as house(s) for butler and other estate staff.  Many modern plans are designed with some of these old 'plantation-style' architecture senses in-mind.

Comment: I duplicated this thread because I needed a new tack to discover the elusive word. I lived in that spot 20 years ago. The circular paved area was in one perspective the habitat of all that is important in life: marriage, children, friends, family, everyday industry and happiness, financial and physical security. In another perspective the circular drive indicated a certain confinement and boredom. There was a sense that one of the four cars routinely leaving the encirclement every morning would drive on one day and never return again. What name for the encirclement would carry that sense?

Comment: Probably 'hallowed ground'.  I don't think there is a term for it that includes the notion of a street, per-se.  Gypsy language many have a word for it, considering their semi-nomadic lifestyle